# Compile R on Windows - Cannot Create Directory

Tags: r, mingw-w64

I'm trying to install R from source on Windows with OpenBLAS.

I (mainly) followed the steps here;

https://www.avrahamadler.com/r-tips/build-openblas-for-windows-r64/

I have OpenBLAS compiled, and R seems to work. However, in the `Makefile` script once you get to the `rpackages` section it crashes with this;

```
C:\R64\src\gnuwin32>make rpackages
building package 'base'
cannot create /tmp/R17244: directory nonexistent
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/R17244': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [mkR1] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make: *** [rpackages] Error 2
```

So it feels like R is trying to setup a temporary directory at `/tmp`, but that directory won't exist on a Windows system. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the official guide to compiling on windows is in the [R administration and installation guide](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Building-from-source). There a section that says "Set the environment variable TMPDIR to the absolute path to a writable directory, with a path specified with forward slashes and no spaces. (The default is /tmp, which may not be useful on Windows.)"

Comment: Oy vey. Always one little line you miss. Thanks so much!